# How to change all projects in a solution file to C++17 MSVC?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS2017 (Version 15.9.12) and generated a solution file with CMake 3.14 for the VS compiler Visual Studio 15 2017.
I want to use some C++17 features. When I have a look in the property page of a project the field C/C++->Language->C++ Language Standard is empty. There I can change it to /std:c++17 (and some other options).

Since the code is an external project I do not want to change the CMake file to add CXX_Standard 17.

Does visual studio set a compiler with C++17 option for a whole project or do I have to change this for each subprojects manually?

Comment: what is the "whole project", the solution?

Comment: Yes, the "whole project" is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to change this for each subproject.  Alternatively just run `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 -S /path/to/external/project -B bld` (for example) and CMake will generate the projects with the desired standard (unless overridden by CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: The idea to just add the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 argument gives me the right hint and i guess it will work in most cases. Therefore, I will mark this as an answer.